# How to pass a directive as an attribute to another directive ? AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

The idea is that it should work as follows,

```
//This is  pseudo code: 
directives = [directive1, directive2, directive3]
<ng-repeat directive in directives>
  <main-directive attribute = "{{directive}}">

  </main-directive>
</ng-repeat>
```

I have a list of directives, that I need to loop through. The issue is, I can't hard code into the main directive because  I need to add each custom directive one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [$compile service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) in a custom directive:

```
app.directive("dynamicComponent", function($compile) {
  return {
    link: postLink
  };
  function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
    var comp = scope.$eval(attrs.componentName);
    var html = `
       <${comp}>
       </${comp}>
    `;
    var linkFn = $compile(html);
    elem.append(linkFn(scope));
  }
});
```

Usage:

```
<div ng-repeat="name in ['comp-a','comp-b']">
    <dynamic-component  component-name="name">
    </dynamic-component>
</div>
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/UyLory5OREfa4DMhemTs?p=preview)